# Big O for a for loop with multiple conditions

Tags: java, big-o

I don't know if this has been asked before since I wasn't sure how to formulate my search, but I'll try. What is the Big O for this code below?

```
List<SomeObject> list = //... List is created here    .1

int sum = 0;                                          .2

for(int i = 0; i < list.size() && i < 75000; i++){    .3
    sum++;                                            .4
}
```

The way I see it is that line 1, 2 and 4 are O(1). And then line 3 is O(N) since it doesn't take *the same amount of time every time it is called*. The size of the list will affect the amount of iterations. This meaning that the whole block of code ends up as O(N). Or is this total nonsense?

Comment: That sounds mostly correct to me. Note that for `N > 75000`, the loop only iterates `75000` times, but it is still `O(N)` in the worst case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List creation isn't necessarily O(1), could be O(N).

Line 2 is obviously O(1).

The loop I would argue is O(1) as well, since it is limited to 75000 entries, so there's an upper bound. Without the i<75000 restriction it would be O(N), as you correctly stated.

So lines 2-4 I'd say are O(1), line 1 really depends on the list creation process, which you omitted.

Comment: So would you say that if I do i < Integer.MAX_VALUE in the second condition would still be O(1) ?

Comment: This becomes a bit philosophical, but speaking mathematically, I'd say yes, it's O(1). For any practical purposes, I'd consider it O(N), because that's essentially the effect.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: If you restrict it to 10 instead of 75000, practically anybody would say O(1), so if you consider a limit of say 2 billion O(N), what's the limit where it becomes O(N)? That's what I mean by it is becoming philosophical. On a more serious note: An O(1) algorithm can in practice be slower than an O(N) algorithm, it depends on the constant...

Comment: @Demosthenes Very interesting. Totally makes sense! But isn't the pure definition of O(1) that it takes equal resources no matter the size of the input? In this case the size of the list varies, wouldn't that mean that needed resources (e.g. time) is bigger when input increases?

Comment: We're talking run time here, not memory complexity. And no, O(1) doesn't mean the run time is equal no matter the input. O(1) means that asymptotically, it is constant, that is for N towards infinity, it approaches a constant, which it clearly does in this case (the run time for N=75000 is the upper bound).

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the implementation of the `List`.

Both initialization (`.1`) and `list.size()` (`.3`) can have different complexity.

Creation can be of any complexity.

And if `list.size()` is not `O(1)`, then the loop will be quadratic - `O(n^2)`. For example, for `ConcurrentSkipListSet`.

Comment: Only if list.size() is indeed executed every iteration. If the compiler manages to optimize it away knowing the list won't be changed, list.size() can be linear without the loop becoming quadratic. - But yes, a lot depends on the implementation of the list.

Comment: @Demosthenes If run multiple times, it can also be JIT compiled and can change the complexity of `list.size()` mid-loop.

Comment: If list.size() isn't constant and indeed called every iteration, then, with the same argument as in my answer, the overall complexity of the loop becomes whatever the complexity of list.size() is.